# View Accounts button in FastLink

Tags: yodlee

I successfully integrated with fastLink for the most part. However, there is a button on the page that shows up after linking an account that goes to a blank page.

On the page that says: "We have successfully gathered your account details." there are three buttons: "Add Accounts", "View Accounts", "Close". The middle one with text "View Accounts" when clicked goes to a blank page.

Looking at network traffic the button triggers a call to: 
https://fastlink.yodlee.com/appscenter/fastlinksb/accountSummary.fastlinksb.do?...
The HTTP response has a 200 status code and a blank body. Nothing comes back.

Please let me know how I can fix this or remove/hide this button. Is there a parameter I can include when opening the iframe that would configure this button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. This portal was created for testing purpose and hence is not completely optimized. The view account button should not be present for YI customers. In production we don't expose this button. We will get this fixed here too ASAP.

Comment: The "View Accounts" button has been removed.